# scale_y_log10() and coord_trans(ytrans = 'log10') lead to different results

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using log transforms for my statistical analyses (reaction times) and now I want to plot my data, with a log transformed y-axis. When I use coord_trans(ytrans = "log10") that gives me the right results - but I need bars instead of points for my graph.
When I use scale_y_log10() it works with bars but it plots the wrong values (bar1 has a mean of 833 but is shown above 900; bar2 has a mean of 568 but is shown closer to 500).

```
set.seed(10)

bar1 <- abs(rnorm(n = 232, mean = 833, sd = 1103)) + 1
bar2 <- abs(rnorm(n = 393, mean = 568, sd = 418)) + 1

graph_data <- data.frame(RT = c(bar1, bar2), group = c(rep(1, 232), rep(2, 393)))

ggplot(graph_data, aes(group, RT)) +
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = 'point', position = 'dodge') +
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = 'pointrange', position = 'position_dodge'(width = .9)) +
coord_trans(ytrans = "log10")

ggplot(graph_data, aes(group, RT)) +
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = 'bar', position = 'dodge') +
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = 'pointrange', position = 'position_dodge'(width = .9)) +
scale_y_log10(breaks = seq(300, 1000, 100))
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There two reasons why you got different values.

First, if you will look on the help page of the `coord_trans()` you will see that:

> coord_trans is different to scale transformations in that it occurs
>   after statistical transformation and will affect the visual appearance
>   of geoms - there is no guarantee that straight lines will continue to
>   be straight.

This mean that with `coord_trans()` only coordinates (y axis) are affected with log10 but with `scale_y_log10()` your actual data are log transformed before other calculations.

Second, your data have negative values and when you apply `scale_y_log10()` to your data those values are removed and all calculations are made with only part of your data, so the mean value you get is larger as with `coord_trans()`.

```
Warning messages:
1: In scale$trans$trans(x) : NaNs produced
2: In scale$trans$trans(x) : NaNs produced
3: Removed 100 rows containing missing values (stat_summary). 
4: Removed 100 rows containing missing values (stat_summary).
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realize that I didn't choose my example data carefully enough. My real data does not have any negative values or values below 1 (I am looking at reaction times measured in milliseconds).
Does it usually make a difference in the means if the axis is transformed (`coord_trans()`) or the data (`scale_y_log()`)?

Comment: I eliminated negative values and values below 1 from the sample data above and `coord_trans()` and `scale_y_log10()` still give different results.

Comment: Yes, it makes difference, because with coord_trans() only look of axis is affected but with scale_y_log10() log10 is taken from your data then mean is calculated and results are back transformed. Compare those two results `mean(1:10)` and `10^mean(log10(1:10))`

Comment: I've been using ggplot for 5 years and only just learned this. Wow this is not very obvious.   One thing is you get the wrong geom_smooth if you use the wrong transformation function.