# How to scale y axis with specified values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I am trying to scale my y-axis to work like this:

[image]

So I tried the following: 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 0.9, 0.99, 0.999))

However, the results are:

[image]
How can I scale the graph accordingly to the numbers specified? More specifically, can I scale the graph according to an array of values? say c = (0, 0.9, 0.99, 0.999).

Here's the code I wrote so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
library(scales)

results = read.csv("results.csv")
breaks = c(0, 0.9, 0.99, 0.999)

ggplot(data=results, aes(x=t, y=Values, group=Algorithm, color = factor(Algorithm), shape = factor(Algorithm))) +
  geom_line(size = 1)+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="top") + 
  labs(color="") +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=16),
        legend.text=element_text(size=16)) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks=breaks, labels=breaks)
```

Sample CSV data:

```
t,Algorithm,Values
0,alg1,0.000000000000
0,alg2,0.000000000000
0,alg3,0.000000000000
0,alg4,0.000000000000
0,alg5,0.000000000000

100,alg1,0.950000000000
100,alg2,0.950000000000
100,alg3,0.950000000000
100,alg4,0.000000000147
100,alg5,0.000000000000

200,alg1,0.950000000005
200,alg2,0.950000000000
200,alg3,0.950000001250
200,alg4,0.004578701861
200,alg5,0.000000182645

250,alg1,0.950000259280
250,alg2,0.950000000000
250,alg3,0.950000400517
250,alg4,0.219429576450
250,alg5,0.000199361725

300,alg1,0.950314820965
300,alg2,0.950000000000
300,alg3,0.950037201876
300,alg4,0.824669958806
300,alg5,0.012390843342

400,alg1,0.992274938722
400,alg2,0.950000000000
400,alg3,0.959167637150
400,alg4,0.936487596777

400,alg5,0.603221722035
500,alg1,0.998314400000
500,alg2,0.998334835568
500,alg3,0.995747486022
500,alg4,0.978514678505
500,alg5,0.917973600000

600,alg1,0.998314400000
600,alg2,0.999100000000
600,alg3,0.999118983394
600,alg4,0.998040800000
600,alg5,0.917973600000
```

Comment: use logarithmic scale

Comment: Try replacing `scale_y_continuous` with `scale_y_log10`. Consider adding a small data.frame of test data to make your code 'reproducible'. Also check out http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html

Comment: Post a representative sample of your data and script here vs link to a sketchy ad-driven site.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I have updated my question.

Comment: You may want to use `dput`.

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand from your data, it seems that you want to zoom in your plot to see how data in the range `(0.9 - 0.99)` is distributed. In `ggplot` it is recommend to use `facets` that help highlight the important segments in your data.

You can choose to create `facets` by dividing your data into multiple segments (range in your case) of interest. Something like below creates 3 segments out of your range.

```
   library(dplyr) 

   results = results %>% 
      mutate(grp = case_when(Values<0.9 ~ "0 - 0.9",
                             Values>=0.9 & Values<0.99 ~ "0.9 - 0.99",
                             Values>=0.99 ~ "0.99+"))

    results %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = t, y = Values, group = Algorithm, color = Algorithm)) +
      geom_line(size = 1) + 
      facet_wrap(~grp, scales = "free") +
      theme(legend.position="top") + 
      labs(color="") +
      theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
            axis.title=element_text(size=16),
            legend.text=element_text(size=16))
```

[image]

Alternately, you can choose to display the whole data in one chart and create facets with the segments of your choice. Below I show only one segment in which you can zoom in.

```
    plot_df = bind_rows(`All Data` = results, 
                        `Segment (0.9 - 0.99)` = results %>% filter(grp=="0.9 - 0.99"), 
                        .id = "Groups")

    plot_df %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = t, y = Values, group = Algorithm, color = Algorithm)) +
      geom_line(size = 1) + 
      facet_wrap(~Groups, scales = "free") +
      theme(legend.position="top") + 
      labs(color="") +
      theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
            axis.title=element_text(size=16),
            legend.text=element_text(size=16))
```

[image]

It is not a good idea to break scale in one plot as it may lead to wrong interpretations by users.

**Edit:**

The graph in your question is reproducible using a user-defined scale transform as below.

```
    library(scales)
    foo_trans = function() trans_new("foo", function(x) log(1/(1-x)), function(x) -1/exp(x) + 1)

    results %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = t, y = Values, group = Algorithm, color = Algorithm)) +
      geom_line(size = 1) + 
      theme(legend.position="top") + 
      labs(color="") + ylab("Values (Tranformed Scale)") +
      theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
            axis.title=element_text(size=16),
            legend.text=element_text(size=16)) +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,0.9,0.99,0.999), labels = c(0,0.9,0.99,0.999)) +
      coord_trans(y = "foo")
```

[image]

As you see for your toy example, the y-axis was transformed using the code and no data transformation was applied. Computationally this can be done, I but I will prefer the first solution for representation. You may want to refer to additional answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256232/scale-y-log10-and-coord-transytrans-log10-lead-to-different-results) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57429/functions-similar-to-log-but-with-results-between-0-and-1) to work out your actual problem.

Comment: I updated the question to include a working example. Using coord_trans(y = "log10") did not work.

Comment: While this answer technically gives an alternative solution, this is not what I am looking for. Nevertheless, upvoted, thanks :)

Comment: What you ask in your original problem is possible through `coord_trans`, but then it becomes a scale transformation problem which is better solved at math.stackexchange.com. I am giving here my solution to your toy problem, but your actual problem might need a different transform.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [scale_y_log10](http://ggplot.yhathq.com/docs/scale_y_log10.html)

replace `scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 0.9, 0.99, 0.999))` with `scale_y_log10(breaks=c(0, 0.9, 0.99, 0.999))`

Comment: This doesn't work. I receive the warning: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis which screws up the results.

Comment: Are any of your y-values zero or negative? You can't put those on a log scale. Try subsetting your data `subset(results, Values > 0)`. Also, you should remove "0" from your vector of breaks.

Comment: although I don't want to remove the 0 values, I did and it didn't work. I updated the question to reflect more details.