# plotting a strait line in R (ggplot2) with a log scale?

Tags: r, logging, ggplot2

Okay, so I am attempting (and failing) to reproduce a plot showing secular market trends of the S&P 500.

Because I am showing the plot with the y-axis in log scale the connecting lines are curved. I would like them strait. Sigh, but I am failing epically!!!

[image: Log scale of S&P 500]

Code:

```
SP500.1950 <- read.csv("SP1950.csv")
colnames(SP500.1950) <- "Price"
SP500.1950 <- xts(SP500.1950[,-1], order.by=as.Date(SP500.1950[,1]))
SP500 <- get.Quantmod.Yahoo(symbol = "^GSPC",startDate = "1900-12-31")
SP500 <- SP500[endpoints(SP500,on = "months"),]
colnames(SP500) <- "Price"

SP500 <- rbind(SP500.1950,SP500) 
colnames(SP500) <- "Price"



x10 <- SP500[index(SP500) == "1900-01-01",]
x10[1,1] = 8.21
x10 <- rbind(x10,SP500[index(SP500) == "1922-04-01",])
x10 <- rbind(x10,SP500[index(SP500) == "1929-09-01",])
x10 <- rbind(x10,SP500[index(SP500) == "1932-07-01",])
x10 <- rbind(x10,SP500[index(SP500) == "1937-02-01",])
x10 <- rbind(x10,SP500[index(SP500) == "1950-04-28",])
x10 <- rbind(x10,SP500[index(SP500) == "1966-02-28",])
x10 <- rbind(x10,SP500[index(SP500) == "1978-10-31",])
x10 <- rbind(x10,SP500[index(SP500) == "2000-03-31",])
x10 <- rbind(x10,SP500[index(SP500) == "2013-01-31",])
SP500.max <- subset(SP500, as.Date(index(SP500)) > as.Date("2009-03-2009"))
x20 <- period.max(SP500.max[,1],endpoints(SP500.max))
x10 <- rbind(x10,x20[nrow(x20),])



#2013-01-31
  gg.sp500sc <- ggplot(SP500,aes(x=as.Date(index(SP500)),y = SP500[,1])) + 
    theme_minimal() + 
    theme() + 
    geom_line()+
    geom_line(data = x10, aes(x = as.Date(index(x10)),y=x10[,1]), color = "blue",size = 1) + 
    ggtitle("S&P 500 Index Secular Chart") + 
    coord_trans(y = "log") +
    xlab("") + 
    xlab("")
  gg.sp500sc
```

Any thoughts on a quick fix?

Cheers, 
Sody

---

### EDIT

Thanks for the help, here is the result: 
[image: complete picture]

Comment: Try using `scale_y_log10()` instead of `coord_trans(y="log")`. This Q seems relevant (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256232/scale-y-log10-and-coord-transytrans-log10-lead-to-different-results)

Comment: BINGO!!!! That did it, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that a coordinate transformation occurs after the statistical transformation, which changes how geoms appear. Try replacing `coord_trans(y = "log")` with `scale_y_continuous(trans = "log")`. Here is a small reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(888)

d <- data_frame(
  x = 1:1000,
  y = x + 10 + rnorm(1000)
)

d2 <- filter(d, x %in% c(50, 500))

ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = d2, color = "blue") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log")
```

Comment: They are slightly different solutions. "log" is natural log and `scale_y_log10()` is a shortcut to do a log 10 transformation of the y scale.

Comment: I agree they are different,  log10 transformation works for the scale of the plot, so I see no issue using either one. (just visual effects)